# how to dynamically change userControl on button (click) present in the usercontrol in wpf MVVM light

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I have a Main Window that host  Usercontrol as ContentControl host.What i want is, to dynamically change usercontrol on button click(present in the first Usercontrol ) to another usercontrol.

Currently I have created a DataTemplate in the Main Window resources consisting of the respective ViewModel of the usercontrol

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Tube:ViewModel1}" >
        <Tube:View1/>
 </DataTemplate>

 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Tube1:ViewModel2}">
        <Tube2:View2/>
 </DataTemplate>
```

I want to change to from View1 to view2 on button click present in view1. So what should i do in ViewModel1(US1 viewModel) to change to US2

I am currently working on MVVM light.

I have a service locator that has the registered instance of each VM. The problem is how can i point to VM2 instance in VM1.

Any help is welcomed!!!!!

Comment: what was the common VM for these views?

Comment: There are 3 VM 1 Main VM for the MainWIndow and 2 US VIewModel for the respective views

Comment: @Sankarann I have edidted the question....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treat your Window as shell and send messages using MvvmLight's Messenger to your shell in order to swap views.

for example:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel></local:MainWindowViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Command="{Binding ChangeFirstViewCommand}">Change View #1</Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding ChangeSecondViewCommand}">Change View #2</Button>
        <ContentControl  Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="{Binding ContentControlView}"></ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private FrameworkElement _contentControlView;
        public FrameworkElement ContentControlView
        {
            get { return _contentControlView; }
            set
            {
                _contentControlView = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ContentControlView");
            }
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            Messenger.Default.Register<SwitchViewMessage>(this, (switchViewMessage) =>
            {
                SwitchView(switchViewMessage.ViewName);
            });
        }

        public ICommand ChangeFirstViewCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                    SwitchView("FirstView");

                });
            }
        }


        public ICommand ChangeSecondViewCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                    SwitchView("SecondView");
                });
            }
        }

        public void SwitchView(string viewName)
        {
            switch (viewName)
            {
                case "FirstView":
                    ContentControlView = new FirstView();
                    ContentControlView.DataContext = new FirstViewModel() { Text = "This is the first View" };
                    break;

                default:
                    ContentControlView = new SecondView();
                    ContentControlView.DataContext = new SecondViewModel() { Text = "This is the second View" };
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FirstView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.FirstView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label>This is the second view</Label>
        <Label Content="{Binding Text}" />
        <Button Command="{Binding ChangeToSecondViewCommand}">Change to Second View</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

FirstViewModel.cs

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class FirstViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        private string _text;
        public string Text
        {
            get { return _text; }
            set
            {
                _text = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Text");
            }
        }

        public ICommand ChangeToSecondViewCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                    Messenger.Default.Send<SwitchViewMessage>(new SwitchViewMessage { ViewName = "SecondView" });
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SecondView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.SecondView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label>This is the second view</Label>
        <Label Content="{Binding Text}" />
        <Button Command="{Binding ChangeToFirstViewCommand}">Change to First View</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

SecondViewModel.cs

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class SecondViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        private string _text;
        public string Text
        {
            get { return _text; }
            set
            {
                _text = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Text");
            }
        }

        public ICommand ChangeToFirstViewCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                    Messenger.Default.Send<SwitchViewMessage>(new SwitchViewMessage { ViewName = "FirstView" });
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SwitchViewMessage.cs

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class SwitchViewMessage
    {
        public string ViewName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your MainViewModel make a property eg "DisplayViewModel" with the basetype of your vm1 and vm2.

```
private MyViewModelBase _displayViewModel;

public MyViewModelBase DisplayViewModel
{
    get { return _displayViewModel; }
    set 
    { 
        _displayViewModel = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("DisplayViewModel"); // Raise PropertyChanged
    }
}
```

In your MainView.xaml insert a ContentControl which binds to the DisplayViewModelProperty :

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding DisplayViewModel}" />
```

On your Button-Command you can Modify the DisplayProperty via Setter with another ViewModel and in combination with your DataTemplates the UserControl displayed by the ContentControl should change to the View according to the newly set ViewModel-Type.

```
private void MyButtonCommand()
{
    DisplayViewModel = new ViewModel2();
}
```

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood that your button isn´t on your main viewmodel.

Comment: If your MainViewModel knows both ViewModels vm1 and vm2 you could implement an event "SwitchViewModel" in your vm1 and vm2 and fire this event upon button command. In your eventhandler in the MainViewModel you could then modify your DisplayViewModel property which causes the UI to switch to the other UserControl according to DataTemplate.