# Best way to implement communication between two view models

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

We have implement two forms (Display form and action form) with two view models (DiplayViewModel and AcdtionViewModel).

In Display form only list of products using list view should be displayed. 
And in Action form should allow add/update/delete operations on the list displayed in Display form.

Can any help share if any sample application is available or guide us through the best way to implement the above.

Answer (score 0):

Mvvm-Light has its own messaging service you can look [here](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=mvvm+light+messaging&oq=messaging+in+mvvm&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l4.10680j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8). 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107957/how-to-dynamically-change-usercontrol-on-button-click-present-in-the-usercontr?noredirect=1#comment31756644_21107957) is a basic example how to switch views using messaging between two Viewmodels.

hope this helps.....