# How to navigate between Views/ViewModels in different projects

Tags: c#, mvvm, view, viewmodel

I have 3 different projects for Models, Views, and ViewModels and one other project for UserControls. In the project UserControls I've included a reference to the ViewModels so that I could ViewModels as DataContext for some certain UserControls which I've created. Then in the Views Project I've added a reference to UserControls project.
I have a button in one of my user controls in order to show a View however it is not possible because I don't have any access to the Views project and I can't instantiate any of them since adding a reference from Views to UserControls results in a Circular Dependency issue.

Now I need to know if there are any solutions for this problem of mine please. Please let me know if I haven't explained my situation very clearly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may find this helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107957/how-to-dynamically-change-usercontrol-on-button-click-present-in-the-usercontr/21109135#21109135

Answer (score 1):

You have a design problem which needs to be solved.

What i usually do in MVVM projects is have one Main project which holds inside all the views that are created. Then you can have a ViewModel and Model projects if necessary. 
But creating a UserControl which has knowledge of your specific View is wrong. What you can do is put your UserControl in one of your views and and bind to the "OnClicked" event an have that event resolve the proper View you want.

Usually i have my ViewModel reference my Model, and my Views reference my ViewModels. That way you dont end up with circular dependency

Comment: I think you're right. I have a design problem. and actually my Views project is my Main project. But shouldn't a view code be clean? I mean I've seen in tutorials that we shouldn't write any c# codes for views and everything is done in xaml part by binding to properties and command.

Comment: Thats right. You can keep your views clean when you depend on the ViewModel to do the actual work. You bind to it with Commands and let all the logic stay there, keeping your view clean with only XAML code